# iOS Re-Design Released App from Scratch

Tags: ios, core-data, app-store

I have developed an iOS application and it is already in the store now. But in the first version of this app(which is in the store now), I have used Core Data. Then now, I have started to design this app from scratch without using Core Data. By saying without using Core Data, when I start to create a new project, "Use Core Data" stayed marked in Xcode, but I didn't create any entity. If I upload this app to store for update, everything will be OK? or should I do migrations or something special?

Comment: Is it still using CoreData. Is the coreData model changed or is it that you just created it manually. That makes a difference.

Comment: As I said in my question, when I started to create a new project from scratch, use Core Data stayed marked, But I didn't create any entity. There is **ProjectName.xcdatamodeld** file in file inspector. But it hasn't any entity, just default configuration.

Comment: So say I download your update and you used CoreData before. Is there a mechanism in the app that imports my data into whatever you are using now to store the data?

Comment: No, I don't need the data stored in the previous version. Just want to get rid of from the core data used before. Maybe in the next versions I will use core data to store another things.

Comment: Adding the core data model to your project shouldnt be a problem.  If you dont call it, or the entity it shouldn't be an issue. The problem that will come is if your original architecture stored user data in CoreData. If you changed it to another form of persistence then your user will lose all data when they update the app.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Added as a answer. Please accept it, if it helps you. Thanks!

Comment: if you use CoreData in the first version, and you update your app and get rid of CoreData, you may need to worry about how to update your current CoreData database into your new data storing engine; otherwise all of your users current data will be lost when they update the app from the previous version; it is not really clear what actually you are asking about here, because I was not able to determine whether you worry about getting rid of CoreData or worry about the actual migration into your new storage engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the core data model to your project shouldn't be a problem. If you don't call it, or the entity it shouldn't be an issue. The problem that will come is if your original architecture stored user data in CoreData. If you changed it to another form of persistence then your user will lose all data when they update the app.

If your model changes in any way (added fields, deleted fields, field data type or length) you will be required to do a little more work to make sure your existing users don't break their app.